# Celery and custom consumers

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

To my knowledge, Celery acts as both the producer and consumer of messages. This is not what I want to achieve. I want Celery to act as the consumer only, to fire certain tasks based on messages that I send to my AMQP broker of choice. Is this possible?

Or do I need to make soup by adding carrot to my stack?

Comment: soup and carrot? could you give an example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Celery brokers acts as a message stores and publish them to one or more workers that subscribe for those,

so: celery pulishes messages to a broker (rabbitmq, redist, celery itself through django db, etc..) those messages are retrieved by a worker following the protocol of the broker, that memorizes them (usually they are persistent but maybe it dependes on your broker), and got executed by you workers.

Task results are available on the executing worker task's, and you can configure where to [store those results](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/configuration.html#task-result-backend-settings) and you can retrieve them with [this method](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-result-backends) .

You can publish tasks with celery passing parameters to your "receiver function" (the task you define, the documentation has some [examples](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html), usually you do not want to pass big things here (say a queryset), but only the minimal information that permits you to retrieve what you need when executing the task.

one easy example could be:

You register a task

```
@task
def add(x,x):
    return x+y
```

and you call the from another module with:

```
from mytasks import add

metadata1 = 1
metadata2 = 2
myasyncresult = add.delay(1,2)
myasyncresult.get() == 3
```

**EDIT**

after your edit I saw that probably you want to construct messages from other sources other that celery, you could see [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/internals/protocol.html) the message format, they default as pickled objects that respect that format, so you post those message in the right queue of your rabbitmq broker and you are right to go retrieving them from your workers.

Comment: Sure, but can I start celery workers by queueing messages from another app? In other words: Can celery subscribe to a broker and start certain tasks based on the messages that is dequeued?

Comment: if scaling horizontally is your concern, yes that is doable for sure! you just need to push the state to a shared backend as the db (for example for retrieving your models?) or operate only on passed data.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. The message format is pretty much what I am looking for, given that Celery 'automagically' will take care of them by subscribing to a queue?

Comment: yes, read about queue names [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/routing.html#changing-the-name-of-the-default-queue)

Answer (score 1):

Celery uses the [message broker architectural pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker). A number of implementations / broker transports can be used with Celery including [RabbitMQ](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/rabbitmq.html) and a [Django database](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/django.html).

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_broker):

> A message broker is an architectural pattern for message validation, message transformation and message routing. It mediates communication amongst applications, minimizing the mutual awareness that applications should have of each other in order to be able to exchange messages, effectively implementing decoupling.

Keeping results is optional and requires a result backend. You can use different broker and result backends. The [Celery Getting Started](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/first-steps-with-celery.html#keeping-results) guide contains further information.

The answer to your question is **yes** you can fire specific tasks passing arguments without addding [Carrot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/carrot) to the mix.

Comment: Ok seems promising. So I can have an external app running on a different environment to queue a message to RabbitMQ that is consumed by Celery which tells Celery to invoke Task X?

Comment: If the other environment is using Python then it's straightforward and covered in the basic documentation and examples. If you're using another language you could look at the [HTTP Callback Tasks (Webhooks)](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/remote-tasks.html).

Comment: Yes. But the thing is that I dont want to use the Webhooks. As I understand Celery is both the consumer and producer of the messages. I want to use Celery as the consumer only, and have an external producer that Queues due tasks to Celery.

Comment: I don't know how it easy it would be to drop correctly formatted Celery messages onto the task queue directly (without using the Celery library). You could use AMQP directly with a framework such as [Kombu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kombu) and the equivalent in your producer's language. You'd be responsible for the routing/subscription of messages though.

Answer (score 1):

Celery Custom Consumer will be a feature released in 3.1v and now is under development, you can read https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/extending.html about it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to consume message from celery you need to create message thats celery can consume. You can create celery message as follows:-

```
def get_celery_worker_message(task_name,args,kwargs,routing_key,id,exchange=None,exchange_type=None):
    
    message=(args, kwargs, None)

    application_headers={
        'lang': 'py',
        'task': task_name,
        'id':id,
        'argsrepr': repr(args),
        'kwargsrepr': repr(kwargs)
        #, 'origin': '@'.join([os.getpid(), socket.gethostname()])
    }
    properties={
        'correlation_id':id,
        'content_type': 'application/json',
        'content_encoding': 'utf-8',
    }


    body, content_type, content_encoding = prepare(
            message, 'json', 'application/json', 'utf-8',None, application_headers)

    prep_message = prepare_message(body,None,content_type,content_encoding,application_headers,properties)
    

    inplace_augment_message(prep_message, exchange, exchange_type, routing_key,id)

    # dump_json = json.dumps(prep_message)

    # print(f"json encoder:- {dump_json}")

    return prep_message
```

You need to prep the message by first defining serializer, content_type, content_encoding, compression, headers based on the consumer.

```
def prepare( body, serializer=None, content_type=None,
                 content_encoding=None, compression=None, headers=None):

        # No content_type? Then we're serializing the data internally.
        if not content_type:
            serializer = serializer
            (content_type, content_encoding,
             body) = dumps(body, serializer=serializer)
        else:
            # If the programmer doesn't want us to serialize,
            # make sure content_encoding is set.
            if isinstance(body, str):
                if not content_encoding:
                    content_encoding = 'utf-8'
                body = body.encode(content_encoding)

            # If they passed in a string, we can't know anything
            # about it. So assume it's binary data.
            elif not content_encoding:
                content_encoding = 'binary'

        if compression:
            body, headers['compression'] = compress(body, compression)

        return body, content_type, content_encoding

def prepare_message( body, priority=None, content_type=None,
                        content_encoding=None, headers=None, properties=None):
        """Prepare message data."""
        properties = properties or {}
        properties.setdefault('delivery_info', {})
        properties.setdefault('priority', priority )

        return {'body': body,
                'content-encoding': content_encoding,
                'content-type': content_type,
                'headers': headers or {},
                'properties': properties or {}}
```

Once the message is created you need to add arguments to make it readable by celery consumer.

```
def inplace_augment_message(message, exchange,exchange_type, routing_key,next_delivery_tag):
    body_encoding_64 = 'base64'

    message['body'], body_encoding = encode_body(
        str(json.dumps(message['body'])), body_encoding_64
    )
    props = message['properties']
    props.update(
        body_encoding=body_encoding,
        delivery_tag=next_delivery_tag,
    )
    if exchange and exchange_type:
        props['delivery_info'].update(
            exchange=exchange,
            exchange_type=exchange_type,
            routing_key=routing_key,
        )
    elif exchange:
        props['delivery_info'].update(
            exchange=exchange,
            routing_key=routing_key,
        )
    else:
        props['delivery_info'].update(
            exchange=None,
            routing_key=routing_key,
        )

class Base64:

    """Base64 codec."""

    def encode(self, s):
        return bytes_to_str(base64.b64encode(str_to_bytes(s)))

    def decode(self, s):
        return base64.b64decode(str_to_bytes(s))

def encode_body( body, encoding=None):
    codecs = {'base64': Base64()}
    if encoding:
        return codecs.get(encoding).encode(body), encoding
    return body, encoding
```